# Express JS Fetch updates from API in real time

Tags: express, websocket, socket.io, backend

I want to integrate a sports API into my express js backend application, I want to fetch live scores as it happens so I can display in my frontend application and I'm looking for an efficient way to implement this without wasting lots of resources. I know two methods which can be used to get updates in real time from an end point which are:

1. Socket IO
2. Pooling with cron jobs or in intervals

However to get updates using socket IO, I will need the events these end points are emitting so I can listen to them from my backend application, and these API providers don't provide it

The second option which is pooling is not efficient and elegant, pooling leads to waste of resources, is there an efficient way to fetch live score updates from sports API in my express js app or a backend application so I can display to frontend

I have tried using socket io, but I don't have access to even the APIs are emitting.
I have also tried pooling it works but its not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

How to pull odds data from sports api?

> 1. You can get data from api using call endpoint periodically.
> 2. The api may provide realtime api such as WebSocket or AMQP.

You can use socket.io in both case.
Please define global variable or app variable.
ex:

> server.js or index.js

```
const api = require('api');
const emitter = require('emitter');

global.oddsData = {};

api.receive();
emitter.start();
```

> api.js

```
module.exports = {
    recieve: () => {
        // call api or receive realtime data using websocketclient or amqp library.
        global.oddsData = receivedData;
    }
}
```

> emitter.js

```
const emit = () => {
    // todo here add data
    io.emit('EVENT NAME', global.oddsData);
    setTimeout(() => {emit();}, timeout);
}

module.exports = {
    start: () => {
        emit();
    }
}
```